# can we replace IS operator with some other operators

Tags: c#

Can we replace `IS` operator functionality with any other operators or functions or any other except AS?
I have tried to replace it with like this

```
class test
{
Program a = new Program();
ProgramTwo b = new ProgramTwo();
if(a.GetType()?. == b.GetType())
Console.WriteLine("true");
}
```

but is not working for the case of derived object checking with base class so any one please help me how to solve this?

Comment: You are not even using the `is` keyword.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: i don't want to use IS but i want to perform its functionality with some other operations

Comment: I guess you can go through the class hierarchy and test all descendents,, but there is rarely a use case for that unless your code is highly dynamic.

Comment: Then use [`.GetType().IsAssignableFrom`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx). Out of curiosity: Why don't you want to use `is`? Are you working with generics?

Comment: i am juzt curious to replace the operators functionality with other operations

Comment: `is` has many specifics which aren't easily replacable.

Comment: What is `a.GetType()?.` supposed to mean? It's certainly not valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you don't want to use `is`. It is wayyyy more beautiful. The code is generally clearer if you use `is`.

An alternative is `IsAssignableFrom`. ([docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx))

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(object).IsAssignableFrom (5.GetType()));
```

A second alternative is `IsInstanceOfType`. ([docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isinstanceoftype(v=vs.110).aspx))

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(object).IsInstanceOfType(5));
```

The above two are similar to

```
Console.WriteLine(5 is object);
```

See the difference between readability?

Answer (score 0):

*[IsAssignableFrom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.type.isassignablefrom%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)* is commonly said to mimic the `is` operator (with reversed order of operands), but the operator has many nuances which are hard or even impossible to implement. Just look at this code:

```
public static bool TestIs1<T1, T2>()
{
    var arr = new T1[0];
    return arr is T2[];
}

Console.WriteLine(TestIs1<int, uint>());
var arr = new int[0];
Console.WriteLine(arr is uint[]);
```

In case you haven't guessed it, the output is "True, False". Why? Because this occasion is one where C# plainly disagrees with the CLR. You can cast an `int` array to an `uint` array like this: `(uint[])(object)arr` and the CLR will permit you this, but without the `(object)` cast, the compiler will complain. In contrast, the compiler cannot directly affect how the code in the generic method is executed, and therefore leaves it to the execution of the `isinst` opcode by the CLR, which, of course, will allow it.

As you can see, sometimes "`int[]` is `uint[]`" and sometimes it is not, and that's not something you can easily reproduce with another method. If you are going to try this, you'll have to handle lots of cases like these. For example: nulls, nullables, by-ref-like types (*TypedReference*, *RuntimeArgumentHandle*, *ArgIterator* etc.). It would be better to stick with what the language provides you.